# fingerprint sensing device, driver installed, still not detected

Tags: usb

I am developing a website for which I need users to login with their fingerprints. Hence, I recently acquired a fingerprint sensing device (Fingkey Hamster DX). But the problem is that I am not able to use the device in any software although drivers are installed as evident from this result after running

```
sudo lshw
*-usb
               description: Generic USB device
               product: NITGEN FDU06
               vendor: NITGEN USB DEVICE
               physical id: 3
               bus info: usb@1:3
               version: 41.00
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=hfdu04 maxpower=200mA speed=480Mbit/s here
```

Can anyone tell me what may be the error or what I might be missing out. I am not pro at Ubuntu. My system information is :

> Ubuntu 15.04
>
> Memory : 3.7 GiB
>
> OS Type : 64-bit

---

**EDIT:**
Thank you **Helio**, I was perhaps installing the wrong driver before.

Comment: Waht software are you using to read fingerprints?

Comment: Hi, I've tried using following softwares:
http://tryitnw.blogspot.in/2013/02/easy-steps-to-enable-finger-print.html
https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui

Both of them aren't able to recognize any fingerprint devices.

Comment: And it didn't work with fingerprint-gui? Try rhis: http://www.bioenabletech.com/downloads/Fingkey_Hamster/Hamster_drivers/linux/HFDU06/

Comment: Yes it didn't work with any of the software I tried with. The link you provided is of driver for FingkeyHamster, but i have already installed drivers for the device as output of 'sudo lshw' doesn't have **UNCLAIMED** tagged with it.

Comment: You're welcome! I've edited your question to correct my nickname/realname. My name is Helio, without the appended **s**. And I'm not Greek but from Gran Canaria island **;-)**. About the driver, I think that most of fingerprint readers are supported by the driver pack that comes with `fingerprint-gui`. I have a Vostro 3550 with a fingerprint reader and `fprintd` and it works great after installing it's driver (it comes with `fingerprint-gui`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it got solved,

1. Download driver from [here](http://bioenabletech.com/downloads/SDK/Linux/).
2. Extract and install according to manual present in the compressed file. (EN eNBSP SDK for Linux Programmer's Guide DC1-0042A Rev E.pdf)